# Haxe 4.1.5 save data?

Tags: haxe, haxeflixel

I've been modding Friday Night Funkin' lately, and I've been wanting to work on save files. I've tried to use FlxSave, but that hasn't worked. Directly changing the FlxG.save.data values didn't work either. I'm using Haxe 4.1.5. Am I doing something wrong, or is it just a bug? Here's my code for saving:

```
import flixel.FlxSubState;
import flixel.FlxG;
import flixel.FlxSprite;
import flixel.util.FlxSave;
import flixel.group.FlxGroup.FlxTypedGroup;
import flixel.text.FlxText;
import flixel.util.FlxColor;
    public function new()
    {
        //super();
        super();
        //lots of this was cut soo
        FlxG.save.bind('funkin', 'dark279');
                        case "Offset":
                            offset --;
                            FlxG.save.data.offset = offset;
                            FlxG.save.flush();
                    }
                }
                        case "Offset":
                            offset ++;
                            FlxG.save.data.offset = offset;
                            FlxG.save.flush();
                    }
                }
            if (controls.BACK)
                {
                    FlxG.save.flush();
                    //switch state
```

Much shorter than the full thing, but all of the saving code is there.

Answer (score 0):

I really forgot to set offset to the saved offset.. omg I'm so dumb